# How to send email from GoDaddy Linux VPS with gmail SMTP so that sent emails are saved

Tags: php, email, gmail, godaddy-api

I have used the following PHP code to send email, but when I login to the gmail account after sending an email, the email that has sent is not recorded in the sent mail section of gmail. But emails are successfully delivered each time. I can use the IsSMTP() function in my laptop and in that case sent mails are recorded, but in GoDaddy VPS I can not use IsSMTP() but to use IsMail().

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\POP3;
require '../PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require '../PHPMailer/OAuth.php';
require '../PHPMailer/POP3.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->IsMail();
//$mail->IsSMTP(); // if enabled instead of IsMail() an error "can not connect to SMTP" appears.
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'username@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port       = 465;

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com', 'OFFICE');
$mail->addReplyTo('username@gmail.com', 'OFFICE');
$mail->addBCC("username@gmail.com", "OFFICE");//since sent mails are not saved
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->addAddress('to@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Hello';
$mail->AltBody = 'Hello';
$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Godaddy (and many other VPS providers) block SMTP ports in order to fight spammers.

When you are using `$mail->IsMail()`, the e-mails will go via GoDaddy's servers completely bypassing your Gmail account.

Now there is another problem as well, Google protects your `@gmail.com` addresses using various methods (such as SPF), so even if you are able to send the e-mail, it will be most likely marked as SPAM - if delivered at all. Otherwise anyone could send e-mails as you..

I'd highly suggest purchasing a domain (if you dont have one already) and either:

1. Hosting it in [GoDaddys e-mail service](https://www.godaddy.com/en-uk/email/professional-business-email) and sending it via their [SMTP servers](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/server-and-port-settings-for-workspace-email-6949) (their SMTP servers are allowed)
2. Use external service which does not rely on SMTP (such as [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/) and their [PHP SDK](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php) for example, but do your own research for a suitable one)

There might be some other "hacky" ways to still send these e-mails trough Gmail **if you really need to**, such as <s>using VPN inside VPS or</s><sup>[1]</sup> proxying google SMTP externally on some other port which is not blocked. Beware, these methods still require some external service (most likely paid) and **might conflict with GoDaddy's and/or Gmail TOS**

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Apparently most of the VPN providers also block SMTP ports to avoid e-mail spammer flood

Comment: Already have purchased a domain. But my client wants to send their emails using their institutional gmail account. Can I open the SMTP port? I have access to WHM.

Comment: Unfortunately no, otherwise spammers would do it as well and get all these precious IPv4 addresses blacklisted among other things.

Also, now that I've checked, most of the VPN providers are also [blocking SMTP ports](https://airvpn.org/forums/topic/2143-smtp-server-port-again/?do=findComment&comment=2145), so no joy there. Dang it, spammers!